# apt-get update: An error occurred during the signature verification

Tags: linux, terminal

```
Hit:1 http:/ubuntu.melbourneitmirror.net/archive bionic InRelease

Hit:2 http:/ubuntu.melbourneitmirror.net/archive bionic-updates InRelease

Hit:3 http:/ubuntu.melbourneitmirror.net/archive bionic-backports 
InRelease   

Hit:4 http:/ubuntu.melbourneitmirror.net/archive bionic-security InRelease

Ign:5 http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease   

Hit:7 http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 

Get:6 http:/repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic InRelease [3,209 B]  

Err:6 http:/repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

Get:9 http:/packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4,669 B]

Err:9 http:/packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
Fetched 7,878 B in 1s (6,188 B/s)

Reading package lists... Done

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http:/repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http:/packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

W: Failed to fetch http:/packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

W: Failed to fetch http:/repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

how do i go about solving this?? pls note i am new to linux in general.

thank you for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the GPG signing key for the ros2 repositories.

You can add it with the following command:

```
curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

After that run the following again:

```
apt-get update
```

And you should be ready to go.

Comment: Thank you!! Works now :D

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this page trying to solve the following problem, similar to the OP:

```
Get:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease [8993 B]
Err:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

The cause seems to be that the *google.com* URL is not longer hosting the key. According to [this comment in the k8s.io git repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/k8s.io/pull/4837#issuecomment-1446426585) the key is "temporarily" available from the following URL:

- https://dl.k8s.io/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

Thus the public key can be updated with:

```
 sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://dl.k8s.io/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
```